# How to apply custom UIimage to editButtonItem in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, edit, uibarbuttonitem

I'm not sure how to apply custom UIImage to [editButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621471-editbuttonitem).

In my view controller, I configured the bar button item as `editButton`.

```
func configureNavigationBar() {
    
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
    
    navigationItem.title = "TEST"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
}
```

It gives me a default edit/done edit button, but now I have UIImage for the edit button and want to display them instead of the default edit/done button.

I also have `setEditing` function in my view controller to set my collection view cells to the edit mode.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if (editing){
        collectionView.isEditing = true
    } else {
        collectionView.isEditing = false
    }
}
```

It works perfectly until I add a custom UIimage to the editButtonItem.

I tried adding My custom UIimage using the following code.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: Images.edit, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(setEditing(_:animated:)))
```

But when I implement the code above, I cannot trigger the setEditing function; it didn't go in the editing mode and stuck with not-editing mode forever.

I also tried keeping the following line

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
```

and tried overriding the [editButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621471-editbuttonitem) to something like,

```
override var editButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    get {
        var result = UIBarButtonItem()
        if isEditing {
            print("isEdit true")
            result = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIImageView(image: Images.edit))
        } else {
            print("isEditfalse")
            result = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIImageView(image: Images.editDone))
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

but it also makes the view stuck in the non-editing mode and cannot enter the editing mode. (as for the overriding editButtonItem, I guess I'm doing something wrong(?))

Could anyone point me out how to use the custom UIImage for the editButtonItem?

Comment: Did you try to set it using the method instead? `navigationItem.setRightBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(image: Images.edit, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(setEditing(_:animated:))), animated: true)` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624929-setrightbarbutton)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lazarevzubov, I used setRightBarButton() and add the following code and now it works.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    
    rightBarButtonImage = collectionView.isEditing ? Images.edit.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) : Images.editDone.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.image = rightBarButtonImage
    collectionView.isEditing = !collectionView.isEditing
}
```